# Django kwarg always 'pk'?

Tags: python, regex, django, django-rest-framework

I'm working on a django application with django rest framework. I am trying to filter the data returned, using a url like so:

```
router.register(r'^api/rates/(?P<name>\w+)', views.RateViewSet)
```

Here is the view:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    if 'name' in self.kwargs:
        n = self.kwargs['name']
        return Rates.objects.filter(name=n)
```

However for some reason the first kwarg is always named 'pk' no matter what i do. Even though I set it to name in the regex url. But when I add a second kwarg with something like api/rates/one/two, than the entire thing (one/two) is attached to the name key. Am I doing something wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: What's in the rates model? Why don't you use a viewset?

Answer (score 0):

You need set the [lookup_field](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#attributes) attribute. By default is 'pk'

```
lookup_field='name'
```